Apache VirtualHost Config: Require local and accessed only through SSH Tunnel
I have an apache web server working with a subdomain subd.site2.com, it works with the domain without problem. But I need to implement a temporal configuration to make http://subd.site2.com/ run only in localhost of the apache web server, so I can access subd.site2.com through a SSH tunnel in my remote terminal pointing to my server and opening subd.site2.com through http://127.0.0.1:8888/site2
This is how I am implementing my ssh-tunnel:
sudo ssh -i .ssh/key.pem admin@1.2.3.4 -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80
And this is the subd.site2.com.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subd.site2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/public_html
</VirtualHost>

I added a mysite_apache.conf to my website and did the include in the /etc/apache2/apache.conf
mysite_apache.conf:
Alias /site2 /var/www/site2/public_html
<Directory /var/www/site2/public_html>
    Require local
</Directory>

With this configuration when I attempt in my browser the tunnel http://127.0.0.1:8888/site2 it redirects me to my terminal localhost but not the remote localhost (http://127.0.0.1/site2) with the error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
Status 301 Moved Permanently

When doing virtual hosts in this manner, Apache uses the server name to determine which site to serve. If you have more than one site on this port, it cannot know which site to send you to without the domain name in your browser headers. You can work around this by either using a tool such as postman to manually specify the headers, or you can create a hosts file entry with the site name pointing to the local IP you're using, and browse to that domain name, so that the browser forwards the correct headers.
Alternatively, you can change from using a name based virtual host to using an IP and port to listen on, in which case it will not be shared, and only point to your one site.
Example:
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName subd.site2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/public_html
</VirtualHost>

Documentation:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

First, you can just use <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> to bind to localhost. Such a virtualhost won't be accessible externally.
Second, you are having a name based virtualhost, which requires that you use the name in the address line. E.g. you shouldn't use http://127.0.0.1:.../ at all, because it sends 127.0.0.1 in the HTTP Host request header, and since it doesn't match your ServerName, this virtualhost is not being selected to serve the request. When you use name, it sends that name. You can augment this by adding 127.0.0.1 subd.site2.com into your client's hosts file, and then use http://subd.site2.com:port syntax in the browser.

Well, that said, HTTPS is no less secure than SSH (it uses the same security libraries), and it can also be equipped with certificate-based authentication (which is very similar to SSH key-based authentication). By requiring SSH tunnel instead of properly setting up HTTPS you're just giving up convenience for nothing in return. You have to set up SSH and hosts on each computer, and still have to exchange SSH keys and setup proper restrictions in authorized_keys to gain proper security (because giving users full shell access to the server is, after all, dangerous, even without root), while with HTTPS you only need to setup certificates.
You should just setup HTTPS, spin off the private self-signed CA for client certificates and use Let's Encrypt (or, perhaps, even the same self-signed private CA, if this is tightly controlled environment where you are allowed to install CAs into client's trusted stores) for the server certificate.
